# Screen scraping, extract text data from DOM tree

Tags: java, dom, jsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape specific text from a website using jsoup. The text doesn't appear to be in the html that I'm downloading, but rather in the DOM tree. Im not exactly sure how this works because I'm new at it. When I view the source of the website I'm unable to see or find the text that I'm looking for, but I can find it in the DOM tree. How can I extract the data?

Comment: What is the website url?

Comment: the site is: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/308206849?report=fasta